# Parameter is incorrect while Check in to TFS from network drive

Tags: tfs

I am working on VM and I have network drive mapped.In which I have created a workspace (TFS) and mapped to project TFS. I am able to get latest and did some modification. while check in TFS throws an error -

'----Filename-----': The Parameter is incorrect.

Are we not able to work with network drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's able to work with network drivers. There maybe something wrong with your account, for example: the drives owner account and your vs login-in account is not the same. And please run with as Administrator mode. Also check if you can check in files in normal driver on VM.

---

**Update**

Make sure you have gained enough permission with the folder on mapped driver for your TFS account (execute check in action)

[image]

Comment: That is the question Patrick, I need to check in from Mapped drive(shared drive) on VM not normal drive

Comment: Yes, I got it. Check in from Mapped driver(shared drives) should be work. I told you to test with normal drive just want to narrow down the issue. If it can work with normal drive but not work with mapped driver. There maybe some conflicts with your network driver owner account and your TFS account. Or there maybe some permissions of the folder on mapped driver with your TFS account.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But the network drive is file share and I can't see Security tab :(. I have admin rights.

Comment: Could you see the security tab on your mapped workspace folder? such as `share driver:\My workspace`?

Comment: Moreover, do you have multiple users pointing their workspaces to this shared drive? If  so, that maybe your problem and you need a seperate location for all users workspaces. More details please see the answer from *MrHinsh* in this question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfcfdb50-3b6f-4fdd-a2bf-28db89be5a1d/tfs-workspace-mapped-to-a-directory-on-a-shared-drive?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: Try to create another new workspace which only you are working on, and get code from TFS server and make some changes, then try to check in them. To see if it works.

Comment: Patrick I missed to tell you that I am working on Azure VM. I think it will change the story..?

Comment: No, this should be the same with normal VM.

Comment: So you mean to say for Azure VM mapped drive we can check in to tfs? and steps are same?

Comment: Yes,TFS workspace is also supported on Azure VM. And you could check in successfully.

Comment: and If it is Azure file share on azure VM? Because security tab is not displayed on my drive folder. It is file share.

Comment: It doesn't matter, usually the default setting will get enough permission. You just need to make sure  there are only your account  using the created workspace. I'm not sure what's the detail of your Azure file. However, as long as you can get latest on the shared driver then you should also be able to check files back in TFS server.

Comment: Suggest you to create a new workspace and get files down, then try it again.